# SQL to display Square root Symbol

Tags: sql

I want to display the square root symbol in sQL ,ie, if a condition is satisfied the "square root" symbol should be displayed.

Is there any way to display Square root through SQL?

Comment: why would you need that, exactly? why directly through sql and not any programming language?

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN N' √' ELSE '' END`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for getting square root symbol in sql

SELECT NCHAR(8730)

Comment: That is a checkmark sign `✓` , unicode for square root '√' is 8730. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm

Comment: SELECT NCHAR(8730) from dual

Comment: dual is oracle specific, useful as in an a case like this for displaying the result of a constant expression.